# Basic Python Classes - Self Function Not Working

Tags: python, class, oop

I have been learning python for around a week and am trying to set up a basic LRU Cache.

I think I don't fully understand when to use the self command in OOP.

A simplified version of my code is here:

```
class LRUCache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache=[]
    
    def add_to_cache(self, cache, item_to_add):
      pass
    
my_cache = LRUCache()

while True:
     what_to_add = input("What do you want to add?")
     my_cache.add_to_cache(self.cache, what_to_add)
```

I get an error on the self.cache in the last line, "undefined name self"

I'm not quite sure why I get this- to my understanding my_cache is my object and it should be able to recognize self.cache, and uses that attribute within the add_to_cache function.

I tried searching around both here and on google, but was not able to specifically find what I did wrong.

I appreciate anyone's help or clarity on this situation. I am a beginner and still trying to learn. Thank you!

Comment: `self` is not a keyword; it's just the conventional name for the first argument in an instance method definition. Your use of `self` in the *call* to `add_to_cache` isn't defined.

Comment: I recommend https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: `self` isn't a function. It just just the conventional name given to the first parameter of an instance method. Why do you think `self` would be defined outside the method?

Answer (score 1):

self represent the current object on which your invoking the method

if you write `my_cache.add_to_cache(self.cache, what_to_add)`

my_cache gets "transposed" to the self argument in your `def add_to_cache(self, cache, item_to_add):`

imagine having a function, `def test(self): print(self.name)`
doing my_object.test() correspond to putting my_object instead of self, same as doing test(my_object)

and then it would call my_object.name
in your case you either want to do

```
my_cache.add_to_cache(my_cache.cache, what_to_add)
```

or better, since you have self, just delete the cache argument
and in your function use it like that

```
def add_to_cache(self, item_to_add):
      cache = self.cache
```

and you would call it like that

```
my_cache.add_to_cache(what_to_add)
```

hope that was clear

Comment: There's no need for `cache = self.cache`. Just use `self.cache` throughout the function.

Comment: You don't need yes, but it's to make it clear for him that it's the same thing as above, also you may want to use a reference to make it clearer, depends what your aims are

Answer (score 0):

In python self use for the simmilar purpouse this keyword use in java.Therefore in this case self.cach indicate that cache list belong to the my_cache object. Therefore in this way you can not access cache list outside of class because python not which object you are refering.You have to move this add_to_cache method  to inside of the class.
Then it may be look like this.

```
class LRU_cache:
    def add_to_cache(self,what_to_add):
       self.cache.add(what_to_add)
```

Then you can call this method refering the my_cache object.

```
my_cache.add_to_cache(what_to_add)
```

Comment: I am tempted to downvote - 1) `self` is not a keyword in Python 2) this code has a syntax error, since you didn't put `def` in your function definition statement, 3) even without that syntax error, it would raise a runtime `AttributeError` because `list` objects don't have a `push`

Comment: Yes I forgot to add def. I will add it and I will change push to add. Thanks.